# Why is $\Delta^2$ with the boundary collapsed to a point not a $\Delta$-complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

I've been trying to understand where this fails to be a valid $\Delta$-complex.
The only potential condition I thought it might fail on is condition $(i)$ in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* (pasted below) - which, in our case, specifically requires that $\sigma_\alpha$ | $\mathring{\Delta^{1}}$ is injective.

a. Is this correct?

b. Is there a quicker/simpler/ more intuitive way to identify when a space is a valid $\Delta$-complex?

---

The definition of a $\Delta$-complex is:

A $\Delta$-complex structure on a space X is a collection of maps $\sigma_\alpha$ : $\Delta{^n}→X$ , with n depending on the index $\alpha$, such that:

(i) The restriction $\sigma_\alpha$ | $\mathring{\Delta^{n}}$ is injective, and each point of X is in the image of exactly one such restriction $\sigma_\alpha$ | $\mathring{\Delta^{n}}$

(ii) Each restriction of $\sigma_\alpha$ to a face of $\Delta^n$ is one of the maps $\sigma_\beta$ :$\Delta^{n-1}$→X . Here we are identifying the face of $\Delta^n$  with $\Delta^{n-1}$  by the canonical linear homeomorphism between them that preserves the ordering of the vertices.

(iii) A set A⊂X is open iff $\sigma^{-1}_\alpha$(A) is open in $\Delta^{n}$ $\forall \sigma_\alpha$

Comment: It would be good to include the definition of $\Delta$-complex.

Comment: @coffeemath Right - added now.

Comment: $\Delta^n$ with boundary collapsed to a point is homeomorphic to $n$-dimensional sphere, and so most certainly a $\Delta$-complex.

Comment: As @freakish says, there is certainly a valid $\Delta$-complex structure on an $n$-sphere. What you're describing is not a valid structure because in a $\Delta$-complex, as you say, each characteristic map $\sigma_\alpha$ must be injective on the interior of the simplex, and this fails in dimension 1.

Comment: More intuitively, the faces of each $n$-simplex must be $(n-1)$-simplices, at least in their interior. In your case, each face of the single $2$-simplex is a point.